# Sphinx: force rebuild of html, including autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

Currently, whenever I run `sphinx-build`, only when there are changes to the source files are the inline docstrings picked up and used. I've tried calling `sphinx-build` with the `-a` switch but this seems to have no effect.

How can I force a full rebuild of the HTML output and force autodoc execution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems to work if the `-E` [option](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-e) is used along with `-a`. I added it to the `html` target in my `Makefile` and now changes in docstrings are picked up without updating any `.rst` files.

Answer (score 11):

I use the `clean` sub-command of `make` to force a rebuild of the documentation (as @Henrik stated in his comment).

You can issue it as a separate command:

```
make clean
make html
```

Or the  commands can be combined:

```
make clean html
```

Comment: Excuse my unknowingness, but WHERE do I need to issue these commands?

Comment: @AndreasL. in `terminal`, in the doc folder you will have `make.bat` file.

Answer (score 6):

I do not use sphinx-build but with make html I always do `touch *.rst` on my source files. Then make html can pickup changes.

Comment: `make clean` removes files from the build directory, then a following `make html` builds new files.

Comment: Touching the source files can have side-effects. It could make it harder to see what files have changed.

Comment: @Henrik where do I need to run these commands? In powershell and git bash shell it does not do anything

Comment: @AndreasL. `make` must be installed before using it. Installing it in Powershell is explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/808818) for example.

Comment: @AndreasL. There is also a `make.bat` file, which you can use on Windows.

Comment: @AndreasL. You have to be in your project directory to run the commands. You might have a look at [Getting Started – Sphinx documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/quickstart.html)

Answer (score -2):

For Windows users, building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21021830/2023941) to use -E -a option, I updated the make.bat file with the new option

```
> ./make.bat clean
```

make.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
pushd %~dp0
REM Command file for Sphinx documentation

if "%SPHINXBUILD%" == "" (
    set SPHINXBUILD=sphinx-build
)

set SOURCEDIR=source
set BUILDDIR=build
set SPHINXOPTS=
set TARGET=%1

if "%1" == "" goto help
if "%1" == "clean" goto clean
goto :run

:clean
echo.CLEAN BUILD with -E -a 
set %TARGET% = "html"
set %SPHINXOPTS% = "-E -a"

%SPHINXBUILD% >NUL 2>NUL
if errorlevel 9009 (
    echo.
    echo.The 'sphinx-build' command was not found! Make sure you have Sphinx
    echo.installed, then set the SPHINXBUILD environment variable to point
    echo.to the full path of the 'sphinx-build' executable. Alternatively you
    echo.may add the Sphinx directory to PATH.
    echo.
    echo.If you do not have Sphinx installed, grab it from
    echo.http://sphinx-doc.org/
    
    exit /b 1
)

:run
%SPHINXBUILD% -M %1 %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %O%
goto end

:help
%SPHINXBUILD% -M help %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %O%
echo.   clean to make clean. 
:end
popd
```