# Images are not displayed in reStructuredText (.rst) - HTML - preview in VS Code

Tags: image, visual-studio-code, preview, restructuredtext

According to the [docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText), an image should be displayable in the HTML-preview like so:

```
.. image:: /path/to/image.jpg
```

Yet, on [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) version 1.56.2 on Windows 10 with the [reStructuredTest - extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lextudio.restructuredtext), the HTML-preview doesn't show the real picture, but only placeholders.
I tried it with both UNIX- and Windows-like paths:

[image: Image does not display in RST-files]

The code I used is:

```
...
4) ...
5) .. image:: C:\Users\andreas.luckert\Downloads\Step-Functions-page1.png
6) .. image:: /c/Users/andreas.luckert/Downloads/Step-Functions-page2.png
```

Comment: While you got guidance below, any issue with that extension should be reported to https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext/issues I don't monitor questions like this on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided is not to the [official Sphinx docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/), but a wiki page.  Here are the docs for handling [images](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#images).

> reST supports an image directive ([ref](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image)), used like so:
>
> ```
> .. image:: gnu.png
>     (options)
> ```
>
> When used within Sphinx, the file name given (here `gnu.png`) must either be relative to the source file, or absolute which means that they are relative to the top source directory. For example, the file `sketch/spam.rst` could refer to the image `images/spam.png` as `../images/spam.png` or `/images/spam.png`.
>
> Sphinx will automatically copy image files over to a subdirectory of the output directory on building (e.g. the `_static` directory for HTML output.)

So put your images in a directory named `_static` inside your top source directory, then update the relative path to the images as follows.

```
.. image:: _static/path/to/my-image.png
    (options)
```

Comment: In the bottom panel of VS Code it states `</> Use docutils`. I'm not sure whether this implies `sphinx`. What's more, when I click on it, an error message pops up in the buttom right saying `Running the contributed command: 'restructuredtext.resetStatus' failed.`.

Comment: Sphinx uses docutils, which processes reStructuredText to other formats. Sphinx adds features to that core.

Comment: I've just created a `_static` folder in my top directory, but don't know how to "rebuild my docs". As of yet, the picture does not get displayed in the HTML-preview; also not after restarting VS-Code.

Comment: Re/build your docs. It's the same thing. You might need to `make clean` to remove cached files.

Comment: I looked it up in `StackOverFlow`, they also mention `make clean` and/or `make html`, but no one tells WHERE to execute these commands. If I enter it into PowerShell or bash, nothing happens and it is also not combinable with `sphinx-build`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019505/sphinx-force-rebuild-of-html-including-autodoc

Comment: Did you update the page to the image, e.g., `_static/gnu.png`? Otherwise, I don't use VS Code and I don't know what its preview feature supports. To build docs, you would need to install Sphinx.

Comment: Finally, this was the information I needed: `.. image:: _static/image-basename.png` makes all the magic happen after having created the `_static` folder in the root-directory where my `.rst`-file is located. @Steve could you please add this crucial part in your answer that on needs to add `_static` in front of the image name to make it work and that also on `Windows 10` one needs to use forward slashes `/` to make paths recognizable to `sphinx`? Once you've updated your answer with all these details, I'm gonna upvote and accept the answer. Thanks :)